# I'm looking for a code solve vchicle routing problem with time-window and mulitl-depot,using MATLAB Yalmip - CPLEX

Tags: matlab, cplex, vehicle-routing

CPLEX can solve the VRPTW, but I am not sure how the constraints should change after adding multiple depot, and how to add penalty terms for time window violations in the objective function. Furthermore, I wanted to use the number of vehicles as a decision variable, but I don't know how to get start.

Can anyone answer the relevant questions or provide some ideas? It would be even better if there were code to refer to，Thanks !!!!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.